# Sonar: is it possible to give new projects permissions automated?

Tags: permissions, project, sonarqube

we are starting to use Sonar. We want to use it for many different projects. Is there a way to  give a project automated defined project permissions (for example with a name pattern). We found only the way to create a default template for new projects, but with this template every project would have the same permissions and we would like to give them permissions based on name patterns...

Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet - as of SonarQube 4.0, but will be soon: feel free to watch and vote for [SONAR-4535](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4535).